# Meteoric way to display documents as elements

Tags: jquery, meteor

My template and code is very simple and functional, but I would like to do this in a more sane way:

```
<body>{{> tpl}}</body>
<template name="tpl">
    <div id=elements>
        {{#each documents}}
            {{element}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

// documents look like { css: { color: "red" }, text: "foo" }
Template.tpl.documents = function () { return documents.find({}); };
Template.tpl.element = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("<div>", this).appendTo("#elements");
    }.bind(this), 10);
}
```

As you can see, this creates an element using jQuery from a JavaScript Object with its properties that have been stored in the DB.  This is the most convenient way for me to do this, and I'd rather not change it.

My main issue with this is the use of `setTimeout` because apparently the `#elements` element does not exist in the DOM when `tpl.elements` is initially called.  Instead, it seems like I should be returning the element to append, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Secondary to that, I think that using jQuery to append the elements is incorrect.  I also have some validation on the documents via `.allow` on the server, and `tpl.element` is run each time an attempt is inserted even if it is unsuccessful.  I can get around that by using `.find().fetch()`, but then it seems like it has to reevaluate the entirety of the documents when there is an insert attempt and this causes flicker.

What would be the correct way to add elements with a properties object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right to assume this is not the meteor-like way to do it. Generally speaking, the more jQuery you write, the less likely it is that you are using the framework correctly.

The answer is to add more templates. Templates are your friends - use them everywhere. As an aside, try to use something more concrete than `document` and `element`. These have specific meanings outside the context of your variable names.

```html
<template name="posts">
  <div class="posts">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{> post}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="post">
  <p class="message">{{message}}</p>
</template>
```

Returning an array of documents for `posts` will cause all sub-templates to render each time any post changes. However if `posts` is a cursor, the rendering engine can selectively redraw the individual posts as they change. This is why it is generally better to use `find` instead of `fetch` in your template helpers.

---

### updated answer

Meteor just isn't built to do this at all. If you don't use templates to reactively render your data you are going to have a **very** hard time making stuff like this work. The closest suggestion I can give is to look at the [rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) callback. That will fire every time your template wants to redraw itself and you can put whatever manually jQuery code in there. The problem, as you have already discovered, is that `rendered` will probably fire before your subscriptions are ready... and then you are left using timers and hoping that all of your data is there and that it won't change. In short, it's a huge mess.

Comment: I'm not really using `document` and `element`, I was just trying to use them to make it clear for my example.  This does not answer my question, though, which is how to use the property object to create the individual element (in this case `post`).  The properties can vary wildly, so using classes is out.

Comment: I think if you have a careful study of the [leaderboard example](https://www.meteor.com/examples/leaderboard) and its [source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/leaderboard), this may become clear. Can you explain what you mean by "the property object"?

Comment: `$("<div>", this)`.  `this` is the property object.

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. I wish I had better news for you.

Comment: What I ended up doing is `{{{element}}}` and that function does `return $("div", this)[0].outerHTML`.  Still may not be ideal, but it is a bit cleaner and the `setTimeout` is obviated.